# Validate database output using chef inspec

Tags: database, postgresql, chef-infra, inspec

While executing the below postgresql command, how to validate the output under name column and row column using chef inspec.

```
postgres=# select name, setting from pg_settings where (name ~ '_directory$'
postgres(# or name ~ '_tablespace');
         name         |        setting
----------------------+------------------------
 data_directory       | /var/lib/pgsql/10/data
 default_tablespace   |
 log_directory        | log
 stats_temp_directory | pg_stat_tmp
 temp_tablespaces     |
(5 rows)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use 2 postgres resources:

1. [`postgres_session`](https://docs.chef.io/inspec/resources/postgres_session/) to test SQL commands run against a PostgreSQL database

   ```rb
   sql = postgres_session('username', 'password', 'host', 'port')
   describe sql.query('SELECT * FROM pg_shadow WHERE passwd IS NULL;') do
     its('output') { should eq '' }
   end
   ```
2. [`postgres_conf`](https://docs.chef.io/inspec/resources/postgres_conf/) to test the contents of the configuration file for PostgreSQL

   ```rb
   describe postgres_conf do
     its('max_connections') { should eq '5' }
   end
   ```